# Iterating Performance Comparison

Tags: javascript, performance, loops

I have an array:

```
deleteIds= ["User1"];
```

and try to iterate over it as like:

first one:

```
for (var index = 0; index < len; index++) {
    alert(deleteIds[index]);
}
```

second one:

```
for (var index in deleteIds) {
    alert(deleteIds[index]);
}
```

What is the performance comparison of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a ***micro optimisation*** at best. Unless you have hundreds of thousands of elements in your `deleteIds` array, you should not be looking at optimising this.

It turns out that the `for(;;;)` version is quicker than `for in`: http://jsperf.com/iterating-over-a-loop/2 (thanks to @Jamiec for the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com)).

However, what's more important than the performance comparison of these, is that both code snippets are ***functionally*** different to each other ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2usf7/1)).

```
var array = new Array(100);
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(i); // shows 0 - 99
}

for (var x in array) {
    console.log(x); // shows nothing
}
```

Furthermore, if you add methods to either the array, or to an object in the arrays' prototype chain, they will show up in the `for (var x in y)` loop, but not in `for (;;;);` ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2usf7/)):

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {};
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(i); // nothing
}

for (var x in array) {
    console.log(x); // `foo`
}
```

You can use `hasOwnProperty` to eliminate the attributes inherited from the prototype chain, but that won't stop you receiving methods directly on the object ([live example](http://jsfiddle.net/2usf7/2/)):

```
Array.prototype.foo = function() {};
var array = [];
array.bar = function () {};

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(i); // nothing
}

for (var x in array) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        console.log(x); // `bar`
    }
}
```

It is because of these reasons that using `for in` for iterating over an array is discouraged, and the `for(;;;)` version should **always** be used instead. `for in` should be used for iterating over an **object**.

Comment: Here's the jsperf to complete this great answer: http://jsperf.com/iterating-over-a-loop/2

Comment: Very good and important information. Both voting up, accepting as an answer. Also marking as great comment Jamiec's comment.